# NULL values not included in query result

Tags: mysql, sql

Considering the following table:

```
create table inttest (
    someint INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);
```

When I insert some random values

```
insert into inttest 
  (someint) 
values 
  (1),(2),(3),(1),(2),(NULL);
```

and execute the query

```
select *
  from inttest 
 where someint != 1;
```

MySQL returns 2,3,2 but not the NULL value. Is this correct? Should I extend my query with OR someint IS NULL or is it a bug in my MySQL installation?

Comment: @OMGPonies: The question is why that fact doesn't lead the row to be in the resultset. It's because, of course, `NULL != 1` is `NULL`, not `TRUE`.

Comment: I think you mean `someint <> 1`

Comment: @JoePhilllips: Oh, you mean, that thing that does precisely the same job and doesn't resolve the OP's issue?

Comment: @Tom <> is ANSI compliant. It never hurts to get into the habit considering how simple it would be in this case. FYI this isn't an "answer" and I never intended it to answer the OPs issue.

Comment: @Joe: OK, I misread, thinking you meant it as an answer. Regardless, `!=` is part of MySQL. I don't really see the relevance of ANSI; MySQL has its own dialect of SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 1 != NULL;
-- Output: NULL
```

Comparison operators [return](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NULL`.

You're expecting `NULL != 1` to give you `TRUE` but, sensibly, you get `NULL` for the comparison you make. This is because comparing anything with `NULL` is meaningless: **`NULL` is *not* a value!**.

Here's a cunning trick whereby you could get the `NULL` in the resultset if you still really want it. The trick relies on reversing the logic, then manually excluding the `NULL` possibility:

```
SELECT * FROM `inttest`
 WHERE IF(`someint` = 1, FALSE, TRUE);
```

A more obvious approach might be:

```
SELECT * FROM `inttest`
 WHERE `someint` != '1'
    OR `someint` IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I already went for your last suggestion, but was wondering whether it was the right way to go. I still find it a bit hard to wrap my head around, because theoretically you would say that using the != operator you would expect to include everything that is not the compared value, even those rows that does not have a value (aka null)

Comment: @Geert: Possibly, but it's more mathematically correct to say that if you are trying to compare two values, and one is not a value at all, then the comparison is invalid. If I have (a) an "apple" and (b) an "unknown thing", and I compare them, how can I categorically say that (a) != (b)? This isn't a completely precise analogy, but it's close enough :P

Comment: Thanks for the complete explanation and striking analogy :) It made things more clear for me.

Answer (score 3):

Correct. Nothing is equal to `NULL` - including `NULL`. Or more formally, the result of evaluating `NULL != 1` is `UNKNOWN` - and `WHERE` clause predicates have to evaluate to `TRUE`.

Comment: What's this `UNKNOWN`? The manual quite clearly states that `!=` will give you either `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NULL`. In addition, [there is no reserved word `UNKNOWN` listed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). Or were you speaking mathematically?

Comment: @Tomalak - note the parenthical after NULL on the page about [logical operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html). In *standard* SQL, the third logical value is `UNKNOWN`. Is it truly NULL on MySQL? What does `COALESCE(1=NULL,10)` evaluate to?

Comment: @Damien: `!=` is not a logical operator. And MySQL is not the same as standard SQL. That parenthetical appears to be making a link between MySQL and equivalent functionality in standard SQL, but there is definitely no such reserved word.

Comment: @Tomalak - What do reserved words have to do with it? I can't think of any RDBMS's that *do* include it as a reserved word.

Comment: @Damien: I figured that if it's not a reserved word in MySQL, then it _holds no special meaning at all_.

Comment: @Tomalak - if you're only ever going to speak MySQL *dialect*, then I guess it doesn't matter. As soon as you move to other databases, that *do* distinguish between `NULL` and `UNKNOWN`, then you could be tripped up. I'm currently reassessing in my own mind whether the distinctions are important - three-valued logic always takes me time to work through.

Comment: @Damien: OK, so you were using `UNKNOWN` in wider terms. That's fine; I just wanted to point out that it "doesn't exist" in MySQL. In MySQL, the result of evaluating `NULL != 1` is, precisely, `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to think of NULL as meaning UNKNOWN.

In your specific case, `someint <> 1`, you are asking the SQL engine to filter out anything that is not a 1. Since NULL is UNKNOWN, it *could* be a 1 but we will never know. Because of this, the SQL engine won't include it because it's not sure that it's not a 1.